# Count a button press in past 1 hour, it should work even after the user restart the app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i want to count a button press event in iOS in past 1 hour.
for instance, let say i want to limit the user the button press for 10 times in past 1 hour, if the user try to tap 11th time, i will disable it & i have some specific message to show in my app and user can of course remove the app from tasks and when open it again but it should resume the counting & the time should be running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea (NOT tested)

```
import Foundation

extension UserDefaults {
    var buttonPressedCount: Int {
        get { self.integer(forKey: #function) }
        set { self.set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }
    var buttonPressedStartDateForLastHour: Date {
        get { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self.double(forKey: #function)) }
        set { self.set(newValue.timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: #function) }
    }
}
```

```
struct ButtonPressTracker {
    struct Limit {
        let count: Int
        let duration: TimeInterval
    }
    
    // Maximum of 10 presses in an hour
    static let maxPressLimit = Limit(count: 10, duration: 3600)
    static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    // Call this every time the button is pressed
    // Use the returned Bool value to disable the button
    static func logButtonPressed() -> Bool {
        var count = defaults.buttonPressedCount
        let date = Date()
        let lastDate = defaults.buttonPressedStartDateForLastHour
        let shouldDisableButton: Bool
        if date.timeIntervalSince(lastDate) < maxPressLimit.duration {
            count += 1
            shouldDisableButton = (count > maxPressLimit.count)
        } 
        else {
            count = 1
            defaults.buttonPressedStartDateForLastHour = date
            shouldDisableButton = false
        }
        defaults.buttonPressedCount = count
        return shouldDisableButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Tyagi, looks like it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done simply using `UserDefaults`. From what I got, the timer should start when the app is open, and close when the app closes. So for that you can

1. Save both the **remaining time in seconds** and **Pressed count** as `Int` using `UserDefault`, which allow basic Data types to be persisted. You should probably save the data into `UserDefaults` in the `ViewWillDisappear()` method.
2. When you are opening the application. You should retrieve the data stored in the `UserDefaults` in the `ViewDidLoad()` and start the timer/count with the data retrieved.

And vice-versa.

If you want a good resource to learn about `UserDefaults` check [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults)

Comment: thank you Vishal, i was looking for code snippet, and @traun-tyagi's answer worked for me, appreciate your help.